# Program won't wrap more than two images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need help with this short jquery program. I cannot get it to wrap more than two images in the same row. I want this website to side-scroll and I thought this would be the easiest way of doing it but now I'm stumped.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nP3VJ/

```
$(function(){
   $(".gallery").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
   $("#image").wrap("<td></td>");
});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your problem**

Assign multiple objects same id.

**Solution**

Assign them same `class` instead of same `id`.

That's why this doesn't work.

Take a look here: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nP3VJ/1/)**

So, your code would go:

**HTML**(only a part)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <section class="gallery">
        <article class="image">
            <img src="images/front.gif"/>
        </article>
        <article class="image">
            <img src="images/back.gif"/>
        </article>
        <article class="image">
            <img src="images/www.gif"/>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
     $(".gallery").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
     $(".image").wrap("<td></td>");
});
```

Check the DOM in your web inspector, it will show you images wrapped by `td`

Comment: Thank you. I did not even see that.

Comment: @PatrickKrawczykowski : Glad to help :) Why not accept the answer then :P